# How to use Latin Extended Char in Regex

Tags: c#, regex, special-characters

I have list of character which contains both normal special character as well as Latin Extended character. I want to use those special character as Regex.

List of Spcl char:

```
var listAdvSpclChar = File.ReadLines(_spclCharFilePath, Encoding.Default);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string s in listAdvSpclChar)
{
   sb.Append(s);
}
sb.ToString();
```

Output :

```
,.()-"*/#ÃƒÆ’Ã…Â½â€šÃ‚Â¦:'Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Â°?_+~&Â Â¢Â¬Â³Â¹Â¼;\=%Ã†â€™ÂºÂ¯â€¦â„¢Â£$â€¹â€œ]Â¾Â`^Â¡ÂÂµ[Å¾Â±<}Â¨!>Â¸Â¥ÂÅ“Â²Â©Â·ÂÂ«Â®Ã‹â€žÂ§Â¤Â¿ÂÂ­Â¶Â´â€ Â»{|
```

I want to use above spcl char something like below

```
Regex.IsMatch(textString, @"[^" + sb + "]";
```

I am getting error parsing

```
"[,.()-"*/#ÃƒÆ’Ã…Â½â€šÃ‚Â¦:'Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Â°?_+~&Â Â¢Â¬Â³Â¹Â¼ ;\=%Ã†â€™ÂºÂ¯â€¦â„¢Â£$â€¹â€œ]Â¾Â `^Â¡Â Âµ[Å¾Â±<}Â¨!>Â¸Â¥Â Å“Â²Â©Â·Â Â«Â®Ã‹â€žÂ§Â¤Â¿Â Â­Â¶Â´â€ Â»{|]" 
- [x-y] range in reverse order.
```

and if I am adding `\` to each char then I am getting error as parsing

```
"[,\.\(\)\-\"\*\/\#\Ãƒ\Æ’\Ã…\Â½\â€š\Ã‚\Â¦\:\'\Ã¢\â‚¬\Å¡\Â°\?\_\+\~\&\Â \Â¢\Â¬\Â³\Â¹\Â¼\ \;\\\=\%\Ã†\â€™\Âº\Â¯\â€¦\â„¢\Â£\$\â€¹\â€œ\]\Â¾\Â \`\^\Â¡\Â \Âµ\[\Å¾\Â±\<\}\Â¨\!\>\Â¸\Â¥\Â \Å“\Â²\Â©\Â·\Â \Â«\Â®\Ã‹\â€ž\Â§\Â¤\Â¿\Â \Â­\Â¶\Â´\â€ \Â»\{\|\]" 
- Unrecognized escape sequence \Ã.
```

I have the string line like below:

```
00000001,0020,0000000000Ø00027006,paper tape 19 28°,759,1648.000 ,1648.000 ,,06092014,12319999,000100022404,HALB,18.51 ,100 ,FS,PT-S12DS120-28,00166789,01,00000015,,00166789,M,01

00000001,0050,000000000000027006,paper tape 19 28°,759,2280.000 ,2280.000 ,,08262015,12319999,000100023811,HALB,18.51 ,100 ,FS,S75P306P-3M,00166882,01,00000021,,00166882,M,010
```

one of the above line contains `Ø` which is not available in my regex list but I am unable to find the line as error line.

The question is can I use above spcl char in regex

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: So, escape the hyphen, backslash and square bracket `]` and use  it in a character class. Latin extended chars do not require any special preprocessing.

Comment: See my comment. Do not escape inside the regular string literal, use a verbatim string literal (prepend `@` to the regex pattern string). Do not add backslashes before every character, only escape `-`, `]`, ``\``.

Comment: It seems to me you cannot put all these into a char class. I think some of these need to be treated as sequences.

Comment: See [Supported Named Blocks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_12). IsLatinExtended-A and IsLatinExtended-B. Is it what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to escape a few char, see [Metacharacters Inside Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). You can use this code:

```
var listAdvSpclChar = File.ReadLines("Your Path", Encoding.Default);
List<string> toEscape = new List<string>()
{
    @"-", 
    @"\",
    @"]",
};
string escape = @"\";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string s in listAdvSpclChar)
{
    if (toEscape.Contains(s))
    {
        sb.Append(escape);
    }
    sb.Append(s);
}

// And then use it:
Regex.IsMatch("textString", string.Format("[^{0}]", sb));
```

Comment: Some extended Latin chars are repeated, I believe a character class cannot be used since these are most probably sequences.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew or OP's source is a bit dirty...? Let's wait for clarification

Comment: This reminds me of an attempt to clean strings double-encoded in utf8. Without knowing what OP is doing I can't come up with a valid answer

Comment: I am not getting any error, but I am not able to validate the string. Please check the updated question

Comment: Correct that means Regex has to give error for that line

Comment: because Ø is not matching with list of spcl char which I have defined

Comment: @Rocky What you're trying to do is unclear, do you want to match lines that contains at least one of your special char? Match lines that contains only special char or match lines that doesn't contains any special char? Or anything else?

Comment: I am trying to get all the line which is not matching with spcl char which I have defined. it exclude [a-ZA-Z0-9]

Comment: @Rocky Then, you are trying to match all the lines that contains char that are not alphanumerics or in the list you defined, am I correct ? :)

Comment: @ThomasAyoub:I have list of string in which items are like, I posted in ques. above in that item few rows have different spcl. char as well. I want to filter those row which has other spcl. char than my listed spcl char. that's it.